# VB.Net equivalent of instantiating a class and assigning member values in single statement

Tags: vb.net, workflow-foundation

in C# I can use

```
var myUser = New User {FirstName = "John", LastName  = "Carter"}
```

to instantiate a class and assign values to its members in one single statement.

Is there an equivalent in VB.Net?

The reason is WF 4.0 only allows VB expression in the designer and I want to quickly create a default value without using a few assignment activities..

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes

```
Dim myUser As New User With {.FirstName = "John", .LastName = "Carter"}
```